# Trouble understanding solution to Poisson Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, elliptic-equations

> **Example 9.11.** Let $\Omega$ be the unit square. Let $$f(x,y) =
>  e^{x+y}[4\cos(4x)+4\cos(4y)-16\sin(4x)-16\sin(4y)]$$ with Dirichlet
>   boundary condition defined by $g:=u|_{\partial\Omega}$ with $$u(x,y) :=
>  -\sin(4x)-\sin(4y)$$ **Discussion:** The exact solution of this boundary-value problem is given by $u$.
>
> [Source: $\small\textit{Unknown - I do not have the full text} ]$

How?

According to the text, the Poisson equation is $$-(u_{xx}+u_{yy})=f$$ I even tried working backwards - with no success, understandably.

**Edit:** Maybe it should be this instead?: $$f(x,y) =
[4\cos(4x)+4\cos(4y)-16\sin(4x)-16\sin(4y)]$$

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Maybe the solution $u$ is different from the boundary $u$? Where did you find this? Are you sure they're talking about the Poisson equation?

Comment: Nope - it's supposed to be the same $u$. All I have is this scanned chapter. According to the author, it is. I have no experience with PDEs.

Comment: Either way this doesn't work unless the equation is supposed to be $$-(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) = u$$